# combinatorics - take all the balls out of a basket so that number of the balls from each color be always unequal.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

We have $5$ identical blue balls and $5$ identical red balls in a basket. in each step we can do one of these three:

- take a blue ball out of the basket.
- take a red ball out of the basket.
- take a blue **and** a red ball out of the basket.

How many ways are there to take all the balls out of the basket so that, except at first and last, we don't have the same number of each colour in the basket?

---

At first, I wanted to solve this by calculating the ways we will have the same number of each colour and subtracting it from all the ways we can take all the balls out; but I don't know how to do this and I don't even know if this is the best way to solve the problem.
I really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Well, why not try this with a smaller number of balls? Start with $1$ of each. Then do $1$ red, $2$ blue.  Then do $2$ of each. Note that the problem seems to lend it self to recursion.  Let $F(r,b)$ be the number of ways to do it if you have $r$ red and $b$ blue.  Can you write down a relevant recursion?  Even if there are special cases...the numbers are so small that this should not be hard.

Comment: @lulu at first I tried to count them without using any formula but I couldn't organize the path to count them and find a pattern, and so I got lost.

Comment: As I say, start small.  Work out small cases.  Connect larger cases to smaller ones.

Comment: The recurrence relation works, but it's like, super tedious, even for a recurrence relation. But it is 100% the way to go. After school I will post a solution. Right now I have to go to french class.

Comment: Like Lulu said, work from small cases. EG start with (0,0), go to (1,0), (2,0), etc, then (2, 1), (3,1), (4,1), etc, then (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), etc ...

Comment: It's easy to answer this in Excel/Google Sheets. The answer is 180, as shown [in this workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/107G7Zo82DoWN_SMYqOXmJwkh2WIzdUOJ44aIX_BvVbM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @MikeEarnest Can you please explain it to me? what is each row/column and number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're too lazy to manually compute the recursive function, it's easy to let excel to all the work for you. We will make a $6\times 6$ grid, where the entry in the $i^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column (zero-indexed) is the number of ways to remove $i$ blue marbles and $j$ red marbles according to your rules. With Excel's convention of numbering rows by numbers and columns by letters, the entry in `C4` would represent the number of ways to draw three blue marbles and two red ones. In particular, `F6` contains the final answer.

- Fill the first row, `A1` to `F1`, with the number $1$ (if there are zero blue marbles, there is only one way to remove the red marbles).
- Fill the rest of the first column, `A2` to `A6`, with the number $1$.
- Set `B2` to be the formula `= A2 + A1 + B1`. Click and drag to fill the rest of the table (entries `B2:F6`) with that formula. (Each entry is the sum of the entries above, to the left of, and diagonally above-and-to-the-left of itself, representing the three choices of what marble(s) to remove).
- Finally, manually delete the formulas in the diagonal cells `B2, C3, D4,` and `E5` and replace them with zero. (Equal marbles are not allowed in intermediate steps).

The completed result is [in this Google sheets doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/107G7Zo82DoWN_SMYqOXmJwkh2WIzdUOJ44aIX_BvVbM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: That said, this computation is still perfectly doable by hand. There are just 15 cells to fill (because the lower triangle and the upper triangle are the same), so it wouldn't take a minute.

Comment: I just wanted to add that there are a lot of comments saying that recursive counting problems like this are difficult to visualize and compute, and I think this solution plus graph-walking is a perfect way to make this problem much much simpler.

http://prntscr.com/215gdfq

Notice that each corner has a red/blue coordinate that indicates how many balls of each color are left. The number associated with that corner is the number of ways to get there, which is the sum of the left, top, and diagonal numbers. The removed points in the middle are because you can't have the same number of each.

Comment: I still don't understand why each cell is the sum of those three cells. I mean logically. how the summation is equal to taking blue, red and blue-red and which of the three cells is which.

Comment: For $3$ blue and $2$ red, displaying blue with *b* and red with *r* and blue-red with *u*, we will have: 1)rbrbb 2)rrbbb 3)rbub 4)urbb 5)rubb  and if I'm not mistaken there are only $5$ ways to do that, but by your formula we'll get $6$. am I wrong?

Comment: So let's say you are at a point where you have 1 red and 3 blue. There are 3 ways in which you have arrived here: from 2 red and 3 blue, 1 red and 4 blue, or 2 red and 4 blue. So you take the number of ways to get to each of THOSE states, and sum them together. That's why you add those values together.

Comment: I made a small error in the picture I linked, here's a fix: http://prntscr.com/215yvwh
 The list that you made, you forgot 6)uub.

Comment: @Zhuli Thank you very much.

Comment: @Zhuli sorry for the abundance of questions but why do we set diagonal cells to $0$?

Comment: Because those are the states where you have an equal number of red and blue balls and the problem states that that's not allowed.